# AppleScript to prepend date to filenames works only if more than 1 file is input

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I'm new to AppleScript so I'm sure it's something obvious. This works if I have selected multiple files (I use it with the right-click context menu), but if one file is selected, nothing happens (no errors).

The intention is to take some file called `someRandom-imageIdontremember.jpg` and use its Creation Date to rename to `2005-03-01_someRandom-imageIdontremember.jpg` and likewise if I select multiple files.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set selectedFiles to (get selection)
        repeat with i from 1 to (count selectedFiles)
            set aFile to item i of selectedFiles
            set fileName to name of aFile
            set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to creation date of aFile
            set dateStamp to (y as text) & "-" & text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & (m as integer)) & "-" & ¬
                text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & d)
            set name of aFile to dateStamp & "_" & fileName
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Your script works for me, but note that when using the `Run AppleScript` action the workflow arguments (selection, whatever) are already being passed in the `input` argument.

Comment: thanks for responding, that's so weird that it worked. just with one file? thanks for the tip about the args

Comment: oh wow, after editing to use input rather than (get selection), it worked with the one file. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It works with one file when using the `input` passed on run, rather than `(get selection)`

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Finder"
        set selectedFiles to input
        repeat with i from 1 to (count selectedFiles)
            set aFile to item i of selectedFiles
            set fileName to name of aFile
            set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to creation date of aFile
            set dateStamp to (y as text) & "-" & text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & (m as integer)) & "-" & ¬
                text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & d)
            set name of aFile to dateStamp & "_" & fileName
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

thanks @red_menace

Comment: It shouldn't have made a difference, but welcome to Automator.